# Why does anchor outside H2 tag work and not inside a H2 header tag

Tags: html, anchor

Why does anchor outside H2 tag work and not inside a H2 header tag?

This is the first part of my php slider, I would like to have W3C valid XHTML pages so I coded it like below..

The anchor link is not working if I do it the way that it's possible to validate by W3C validator.

I should do something like `<h2><a class="" href="" taget="_blank">Valid!</a></h2>` that is valid but not working.

Begin EDITED
Doctye: `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">`

I have values in my code, my code can be found **below** this line is just an example to show how `<h2>` and `<a>` should be nested, all php code is working and has output. when I nest H2 inside anchor there is a validation problem but it is working, when I do it the correct way everything 100% W3C valid but anchor will not work...  maybe anchor will work when an `id` has been defined to it, I didn't try to define an `id` to anchor..

end EDITED

I use a CSS for an image background file in `<H2>`

When I do the following all is working fine but it will never validate by W3C and the W3C Validation is important for this project.

The code below is my original code, it's working but not valid (H2  inside anchor should be anchor inside H2 tag - [W3C](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML_links_-_lets_build_a_web) )

```
<div class="slide-info">
    <a title="<?php echo Slider_HeaderTitleText_echo($Eerste_Slider_Header_Title); ?>" href="<?php echo $Eerste_Slider_Header_URI; ?>" target="_blank">
        <h2 class="notext txt-eerste"><?php echo Slider_HeaderTitleText_echo($Eerste_Slider_Header_Title); ?></h2>
    </a>
    <p><?php echo Slider_HeaderMainText_echo($Eerste_Slider_Header_Main_Text); ?></p>
    <span class="align-left">
        <a href="<?php echo $Eerste_Slider_Header_URI; ?>" class="purplesmallbutton">more</a>
    </span>
</div>
```

added later: Generated by php (page source and some css from style.css file):

```
`#slider-holder .slide-info { float: left; display: inline; width: 424px; padding-top: 23px; }
#slider-holder .slide-info p { padding-bottom: 8px; }
.notext { font-size: 0; line-height: 0; text-indent: -4000px; background-repeat: no-repeat; }
h2.txt-eerste { height: 60px; background-image: url(http://www.awesomehosting.nl/banners/aanbieding.png); }`



<div class="slide-info">
                            <a title="no title 1" href="http://www.yahoo.com" target="_blank"><h2 class="notext txt-eerste">no title 1</h2></a>
                            <p>Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text .</p>
                            <span class="align-left"><a href="http://www.yahoo.com" class="purplesmallbutton">more</a></span>
                        </div>
```

What should I change to make the link work and XHTML Valid?

Comment: `target='_blank'` is not valid XHTML anyways. Use JavaScript `window.open()`. You can leave of the `window` Object, since it's implicit: `open()`. I put your valid HTML into Firefox and it worked fine.

Comment: anchor inside h2 should work: <h2><a class="" href="" taget="_blank">Valid!</a></h2>

Have you checked the generated from php? Can you post actual html generated?

Comment: what do you mean `<h2><a class="" href="maybe_you_dont_have_a_value_here" taget="_blank">Valid!</a></h2>` doesn't work? that's the proper way.

Comment: @PHPglue: onclick="target='_blank';" is what I use but it isn't the problem.. I believe it's better to use onclick="target='_blank';" my doctype isn't strict, I use: XHTML 1.0 Transitional

Comment: The example code block is with value, I have the correct output if I use the full div invalid code everything is working. The single line is just an example to tell that anchor should be in header tags, question is how to make the H2 anchor code valid and working, if needed I can post the CSS as well ?

Comment: you could also post the final rendered markup (the ones that the browser rendered),

Comment: Is there any CSS that could be affecting this with `z-index` etc? As this should work (http://jsfiddle.net/x7c5b0sh/). Check the code as rendered to the browser for quotes that are not terminated or incorrectly closed tags.

Comment: Can you post the markup generated with the `<a>` **inside** the `<h2>` What do the classes `.notext` and `.txt-eerste` do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you have offset the text inside the `h2`. The effectively moves the `a` out of the `h2` so your clickable `a` tag has also been offset. Offset the text inside the `a` instead and make it a block.

```
.notext2
{
    background-image:url(your url in here);    
    width:350px; //replace with what you need
    height:150px; //replace with what you need
}

.notext2>a
{
    display:block;    
    width:100%;  
    height:100%; 
    text-indent:-9999px;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/x7c5b0sh/2/)

You could always use HTML 5 instead where it is valid to put an `hx` tag in an `a` tag and `target=""` is also valid. [HTML5 Spec](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element)

Comment: Your methode is working in your example but still not working in my slider, I'm still not sure what to change... W3C valid page with slider and source code for slider: [link](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.awesomehosting.nl%2Fonderhoud.php&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&ss=1&group=0&user-agent=W3C_Validator%2F1.3+http%3A%2F%2Fvalidator.w3.org%2Fservices) where do I go wrong?

Comment: Add my CSS above and change the height and width as needed. And make sure to change `h2` to `<h2 class="notext2">` from your link you were still applying the `text-indent` to the h2

Comment: Or remove `text-indent` from your `notext` class and change my `.notext2>a` to `.notext>a`

Comment: I moved notext from `H` to `A`, te new css for notext is: `.notext {
font-size: 0;
line-height: 0;
background-repeat:
no-repeat;
display:block;    
width:100%;
height:100%;` and everything in the slider is working great now! thank you for answer, comments and testing! demo slider only  on valid page: [Slider DEMO](http://www.wmurl.com/index.php) only. Thanks again!